# Regex to validate Text Seperated with Separator

Tags: regex

I need to validate the following String : 
"Ahshshsh|dsadhasd|asdasd"

- The Rule is free text separated with pipe
- Each text should not exceed 50 chars
- Should not start or End with Pipe

Comment: You could do `if(!str.StartsWith("|") && !str.EndsWith("|") && str.Split('|').All(x => x.Length <= 50))` instead of using a regular expression.

Comment: @juharr `and x.Length > 0`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes It says _should not exceed 50 chars_.  There is nothing about not letting values be empty except for the first and last values.  But that might match the intent better than the description.

Comment: Thanks, But I'm trying to avoid code, only using regex ! thanks anyway

Comment: @Anass The only reason to avoid code is if you need to plug this into something that takes a regular expression.  Since you didn't specifically say that I thought I'd point out that regular expressions are not always the only way to go.

Comment: @juharr, Yes I agree with you. In my case I need the regex because I'm using a system already implementing a logic using regex

Comment: @Anass Fair enough.  Though you might want to limit the tags you use for a question like this to just regex in that case.

Comment: @juharr, I Edited the Question to remove the Other Tags, I was not sure if it make any difference as I will use it inside a c# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[A-Za-z]{1,50}(?:\|[A-Za-z]{1,50})*$/
```

should work.

If "free text" means more than just upper- and lowercase characters, modifiy the [A-Za-z] to include the additional characters, for example [A-Za-z0-9] would be upper- and lowercase characters and numbers, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that [a-zA-Z] is the same a _free text_.  Also there is nothing saying an internal value cannot be blank, like "abc||def".

Comment: @juharr Yes, you're correct, although the question isn't specific enough to answer either. I'll expand my answer with some of the other possibilities.